# Matrix Inequality and Higher Powers

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

For arbitrary square matrices $M$, $N$ we write $M \geq N$ if $M − N$ is positive semi-definite.

If $M ≥ N$, can I say $M^2 \geq N^2$ ?

Comment: Hint: What happens in dimension $1$?

Comment: In scalar, it is true indeed.

Comment: Try scalar multiples of the identity.

Comment: No, this is certainly not true for scalars (take both to be negative).

Comment: Counterexample: $M=I_n$ and $N=\text{diag}(-2, -2, \cdots, -2)$.

Comment: But if M and N both are positive. Then ?

Answer (score 3):

This is trivial, but lets close it out anyway.

Let $M=I_n,$ and $N=-2I_n,$ where $I_n$ is the identity.  Then $M > N,$ but $M^2-N^2 = -3I_n,$ which is negative definite.

Comment: M and N both are positive. Then ?

Comment: No.  $M > 0 > N,$  but $N^2>M^2$

Comment: M and N both are positive. Can you give me a counter example...?